# Spring OpenFeign - корректно возвратить 404 ошибку

Tags: java, spring

Используя OpenFeign я обращаюсь к другому сервису для получения пользователя. Все отлично отрабатывает, если пользователь есть. Но если пользователь отсутствует, то по сервис возвращает сообщение с ошибкой и 404 статус. По умолчанию, OpenFeign любой ошибочный статус переводит в 500 и возвращает свое сообщение об ошибке. Мне же нужно, чтобы он просто проксировал как и статус так и сам текст ошибки.

Я нашел, что можно переопределять бин ErrorDecoder и все же получить нужный статус. Но как добраться до исходного сообщения об ошибки найти не могу.

```java
@FeignClient(name = "users",
        path = "users",
        configuration = FeignConfig.class,
        url = "${app-server.url}")
public interface Client {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    UserOutDto findById(@RequestHeader(value = "X-User-Id", required = false) Long userId,
                        @PathVariable Long id);
}
```

```java
public class FeignConfig {
    @Bean
    public ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
        return (String methodKey, Response response) -> {
            switch (response.status()) {
                case 400:
                    return new BadRequestException();
                case 404:
                    return new NotFoundException();
                default:
                    return new Exception();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, все просто, даже не пришлось переопределять стандартные бины. Достаточно было добавить `ControllerAdvice`, который ловит `FeignException`:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @SneakyThrows
    @ExceptionHandler(FeignException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> handleException(FeignException e) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String message = mapper.readTree(e.contentUTF8()).get("error").asText();
        log.warn(message);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(Map.of("error", message), HttpStatus.valueOf(e.status()));

    }

    @ExceptionHandler({Throwable.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> handleException(Throwable e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(Map.of("error", e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```